# Encontrar fila en datatable por atributo value de 2 columnas

Tags: javascript, datatables

Tengo un datatable al cual le agrego filas dinamicamente desde 2 combos mediante js, de este modo se genera una fila con las 2 descripciones de los combos y en el value del td le asigno el id de los valores de los combos, lo que se me esta complicando es validar que esa combinación de los combos no la pueda agregar 2 veces, pero no se como validar buscando esos valores dentro del datable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionando de la siguiente manera, pasando el array y el objeto por parámetro a una función que valida comparando cada una de las propiedades.

```
 existeEnArray = function (array,obj) {
       var i;

       array.map(function (data, index) {
           if (data.prop1 === obj.prop1 && data.prop2 === obj.prop2) {
               i = index;
           }
       })

       if (i === undefined) {
           return false;
       }

       return true;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    <table id="table">
       <tr><th>Paises</th><th>Ciudad</th></tr>
       <tr><td value="2">Cuba</td><td value="5">Habana</td></tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       //Verifica que exta una columna de la tabla con el valor pasado como 2do parámetro  
       function contiene(tabla_id, val){
            //Obtiene la tabla dado su id
            var tabla = document.getElementById(tabla_id);
            //obtiene todas las celdas de la tabla
            var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
            //Crea y asigna la variable que se retornará
            var resultado = false;
            //recorre las celdas de la tabla
            for(var i=0;i<tds.length;i++){
                //Si encuentra una con el atributo value y su valor es igual al que se esta buscando....
                if(getAttr(tds[i],"value") == val){
                   //Asigna a verdadero la variable a retornar
                   resultado = true;
                   //Sale del ciclo
                   break;
                }
            }
            return resultado;
       }

       //Función que devuelve el valor de un atributo en un elemento HTML si el atributo existe, sino devolvera null
       function getAttr(elemento, nombre){
          //Inicializo a null la variable a retornar
          var resultado = null;
          //Recorro los atributos del elemento pasado por parámetro
          for(var j=0;j<elemento.attributes.length;j++){
                //Si el nombre del atributo coincide con el ke estamos buscando...
                if(elemento.attributes[j].name === nombre)
                {
                   //Asigno su valor a la variable que retornaré
                   resultado = elemento.attributes[j].value;
                   //Salgo del ciclo porque ya encontré lo que buscaba
                   break;
                }
            }
            return resultado;
       }

       //Con estas líneas es que puedes comprobar que exista o no el valor antes de ingresarlo, si existe muestras un mensaje , sino añades las celdas a tu datatable
        if(contiene("table",7))
            alert("ya existe");
        else
            //Aqui iría las líneas de tu código donde insertas la descripción extraida de los combobox
            alert("no existe");

        //Si quieres comparar los valores por el contenido de los combobox el segundo parámetro de la función contiene es el ke necesitarias cambiar
        //Quedaría mas o menos así
        //var combo1 = document.getElementById("combo1");
        //if(contiene("table",combo1.value))
        //  alert("ya existe")
        //else
        //  Codigo de Añadir celdas
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Si deseas hacerlo con jquery te puedo decir que te evitas mas de 10 líneas de código es mas simple, se que dataTable es un plugin de jquery pero no se si querías hacerlo con javaascript normal o usando esa librería, si es lo segundo me dices y te pongo el ejemplo tambien.